# (null) deviceType from 00008110-001919EC3CFA801E was NULL when -platform called

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I try to run the app using react-native run-ios on my device, it gives me the above error

"(null) deviceType from 00008110-001919EC3CFA801E was NULL when -platform called"

I tried several steps of pod delete and also deleting the node modules